# Connect to UI thread safely Android

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

Is it safe to use instances of objects which were declared in main UI thread from AsyncTask's doInBackground() method ?

Comment: what do you mean by use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by *"declared in main UI thread"*, threads do not declare anything. I assume you mean declared on the `Activity`. Then yes, just make sure you don't have concurrency problems (e.g. a thread reading while another one is writing on the same instance). `synchronized` and `volatile` are your friends.

Comment: I can't find official java docs on synchronized, can you give me a link or an example how to make a synchronized method?

Comment: `synchronized` and `volatile` are Java.

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe because the Activity / Fragment that created the Asynctask could not be there when it finishes executing, maybe because of a screen rotation. You should pass the object you need as parameters. For updating the UI, you should use the postExecute method.

If you only meant thread-safe, in android 3.x+ should be thread safe if you only use AsyncTaks because AsyncTasks are executed on a serial executor. On Android 2.3 the are executed concurrently.

**Edit**

If you need to modify the UI from the doInBackground method of an AsyncTask, you could use the activity method runOnUiThread

Comment: If the Activity has died, then the instances you passed make little sense as well if they were in the Activity context.

Comment: "AsyncTasks are executed on a serial executor" -> but UIThread is concurrent. And anyway you can force AsyncTasks to be concurrent on 3+.

Comment: Yep, I only read safe and not thread-safe. If the activity is not there the app crashes if the task is stil executing

Comment: But you can't access the UI from the AsyncTask, only from postExcute, which is executed on the UI thread, which is a single thread

Comment: You can be modifying a View from an AsyncTask which is accessed by the UIThread.

Comment: So, say for example, i called a method which updates a textview from doInBackground(), it is going to fail?

Comment: @astralmaster: "i called a method which updates a textview from doInBackground(), it is going to fail?" -- generally, yes.

Comment: @astralmaster you can use runOnUiThread but I doubt it's a good. What do you need to do? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: @alex doInBackground holds my socket connection. And it is not going to finish (therefore cant use postExecute) because I am keeping socket open. But I need to update the UI according to the received information from socket. How would I do that?

Comment: Use runOnUiThread in doInbackground: YourActivityClass.this.runOnUiThread(...) if your Asynctask in an inner class onf the activity

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about Java Threads and objects access between threads.

Please take a look at this example to develop a good understanding about the topic [Threadining Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html)